# free jqgrid - date formatter newformat with time always invalid

Tags: time, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

My attempts to use "newformat": "Y-m-d H:i:s" in date formatoptions always returns the invalid date warning when I try to add or edit new row with correct data (including time, example: 2018-01-01 07:00:00) in this field.

```
formatter: "date", formatoptions: { "srcformat": "ISO8601Long", "newformat": "Y-m-d H:i:s" }
```

Can anybody help me to get this working properly?

JSFIDDLE: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c3cckv9z/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the usage of `editrules:{date:true}` in your demo. The validation rule `date:true` can be used in jqGrid only in case of usage of date **without** time.

I'd recommend you to remove `editrules:{date:true}` or to use custom validation of data instead. You can use custom validation in the old style using `editrules:{custom:true, custom_func: function(value,name,iCol) {...}}` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example)) or to use new style of `custom` callback function: `editrules:{custom: function(options) {...}}`. In case of positive validation the callback function should return `[true, ""]` or `[true]`. In case of validation error the return value should be `[false, "your error message"];`